# Unknown plugin specified in .babelrc, attempted to resolve relative to path

Tags: react-native, babeljs, babel-polyfill

So I've started a new react-native project and copied over the .babelrc file from my previous project.  I've installed the necessary plugins but I'm getting the error

`Unknown plugin transform-decorators-legacy specified in .babelrc, attempted to resolve relative to "/mypath/project"`

I've checked the node_modules in the path and see that the plugin was installed using `yarn add`.  I'm also getting similar errors with my eslint plugins.  Am I missing something in my project setup to have babel and eslint see the node_modules?

Is it perhaps caused by installing `react-native-code-push`?  I think it had some errors when I installed codepush where it duplicated the react pod in the pod install - and so I removed it from the podfile.  Is it trying to use a cached code-push js even though I don't have code push implemented in my react js files?

Answer (score 0):

tra**sn**form-decorators-legacy

You have a typo here.

Comment: transcription error on my part copying to stackoverflow, I've fixed the typo in my question - error still stands

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy -g
```

Answer (score 0):

for NPM :

> npm install --save babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy